# A GRE Geometry Question

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

P, Q, and R are three points in a plane, and R does not lie on line PQ.
Which of the following is true about the set of all points in the plane that
are the same distance from all three points?
A It contains no points.
B It contains one point.
C It contains two points.
D It is a line.
E It is a circle.

Please Help
The answer is B

Only thing I can imagine is that point R must be anywhere on the perpendicular bisector of line PQ except the point where it intersects with the line PQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but I have found that when dealing with GRE questions, you want to solve them quickly and in a minimal fashion, since it's multiple choice.  Consider then the special case where R forms an equilateral triangle.  The center of mass is the one point lying equidistant from P Q and R.  Clearly though there is no other such solution.  The answer must be B then by default.

Comment: Vow Thanks. I was not able to visualize this problem in my mind. Now its crystal clear.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Center]

Is the center of this circle, the intersection of mediators of sides of the triangle .
$$OP=OQ=OR$$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that we can construct an unique circle through ANY 3 noncollinear points.

In light of above information, do you see what point could be located at same distance from the given three points ?

[image]